# Can I save/use a raw reponse body in Karate?

Tags: karate

I want to:

1. Get the raw text from a response body (it's XML)
2. Use that as a string in a JSON request body, like `And request {"externalRawResponse": "#(response)"}`

But, `response` is already parsed into JSON. Is it possible to get the raw text version?

I tried using `* text rawResponse = response` but get the error `no step-definition method match found for: text rawResponse = response`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#type-conversion

```
* xmlstring xml = response
* request { externalRawResponse: '#(xml)' }
```